# curl command not working inside dockerfile but works outside in the same network

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i am writing docker file to install java and sonar. everything works great till java installation. but when downloading of sonar starts using **curl** , it fails. more frustrating is , exact same command works outside docker file, same shell prompt and on the same network.

I am really confused how can this be happen. what silly mistake i am doing not getting.

please see the dockefile :

```
FROM centos:7

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u201
ENV BUILD_VERSION b09

RUN yum -y install wget; wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/$JAVA_VERSION-$BUILD_VERSION/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-$JAVA_VERSION-linux-x64.rpm" -O /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y install /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm

# JDK stripping
RUN rm -f /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/src.zip /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/javafx-src.zip
RUN rm -rf /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/lib/missioncontrol/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/lib/visualvm/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/db/

RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 1

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/latest
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin/java
RUN echo "$PATH"

RUN rm -f /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y remove wget; yum -y clean all

ENV SONAR_VERSION=7.6 \
    SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=

# Http port
EXPOSE 9000

RUN groupadd -r devopsadmin && useradd -r -g devopsadmin devopsadmin


RUN set -x \
    && cd /opt \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc \
    && /bin/bash /usr/bin/unzip /opt/sonarqube.zip \
    && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube \
    && chown -R devopsadmin:devopsadmin sonarqube \
    && rm sonarqube.zip* \
    && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*

VOLUME "$SONARQUBE_HOME/data"

WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY run.sh $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/
USER devopsadmin
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

please suggest

EDIT 1 :

see the entire log :

```
Step 14/21 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d8df8bfdaf5
Step 15/21 : RUN groupadd -r devopsadmin && useradd -r -g devopsadmin devopsadmin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d1a28e9288c
Step 16/21 : RUN set -x     && cd /opt     && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip     && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc     && /bin/bash /usr/bin/unzip /opt/sonarqube.zip     && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube     && chown -R devopsadmin:devopsadmin sonarqube     && rm sonarqube.zip*     && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*
 ---> Running in 2e0d5ad30767
+ cd /opt
+ curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-7.6.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: binaries.sonarsource.com; Unknown error
The command '/bin/sh -c set -x     && cd /opt     && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip     && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc     && /bin/bash /usr/bin/unzip /opt/sonarqube.zip     && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube     && chown -R devopsadmin:devopsadmin sonarqube     && rm sonarqube.zip*     && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*' returned a non-zero code: 6
[devopsadmin@be-deb-prod-cicdtoold-vm newsonar]$ curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/CommercialDistribution/sonarqube-enterprise/sonarqube-enterprise-7.6.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  252M  100  252M    0     0  26.5M      0  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:-- 32.1M
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?  The `bash unzip` line looks suspect to me, but you would see that failure _after_ the two `curl` commands ran.

Comment: Works fine on my machine up to the unzip (which isn't yet installed) - is the host machine a Raspberry Pi, or other 'unusual' hardware?

Comment: actual error is this : 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: binaries.sonarsource.com; Unknown error

Comment: see the EDIT. this machine is VM deployed in azure cloud in private subscription which has private IP address and works behind the VPN client. it was working fine couple of days back till unzip command, but now suddenly starts failing in curl ....

Comment: please suggest. stuck up here ...